# The explaination of Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, variational-calculus

I've recently been studying about the General relativity and Einstein field equation. When I reading of the derivation of the field equation, I encounterd a method called Einstein-Hilbert action. This action is given as
\begin{align}
S_{EH}[g_{ij}]\,=\,\intop_M \sqrt{-g}R\,dx_3dx_2dx_1dt
\end{align}
where $S_{EH}[g_{ij}]$ is the functional of $g_{ij}$, $g=\det(g_{ij})$ and $\sqrt{-g}R\,dx_3dx_2dx_1dt$ is volume element of $M$.

I don't have a deep understanding in term of physics for this E-H action and how Hilbert - Einstein find them in over 100 years ago. However, in term of mathematics, here is what I have learnt from school :

> A spacetime $M$ is a smooth, connected, orientable manifold with a Lorentz metric tensor $g$, a Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ and be time oriented with a time orientation $T$ (a smooth timelike vectorfield on $M$).

> $g$ is a metric tensor on $M$, which means $g$ is a (0,2)_tensor field that assign each point $p\in M$ with a scalar product $g_p:\ T_pM\times TM_p\longrightarrow \mathbb R$. The coefficients $g_{ij}(p)$ is given by
> \begin{align}
> g_{ij}(p)\,=\,g_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_p,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p \right), 0\leq i,j\leq 3.
> \end{align}

The definition of variational operator (reference from Haim Brezis - functional analysis and pde)

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with a subset $A\subset H$ and a subspace $M\leq H $. Consider the functional $J:\ A\longrightarrow\mathbb R,\ u\longmapsto J[u]$. Then the vatiational operator is defined as the Gateaux derivative of $J$ at $u\in A $ in the direction $\varphi\in M$
> \begin{align}
> \frac{\delta J}{\delta\varphi}[u]\,=\,\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{J[u+\varepsilon\varphi]-J[u] }{\varepsilon}.
> \end{align}
> If $J[u_0]=\displaystyle\min_{u\in A}J[u]$ then $\displaystyle \frac{\delta J}{\delta\varphi}[u_0]=0$.

So, with these all background knowledge, is it enough for me to get understand the E-H action ? I feel quite ambigous about the symbols is used in the action, I don't even know what is the domaind that the action acts to, so I really hope someone with knowledge would help me to clarify this ambigousness. Thanks.

Comment: $S$ maps $g_{ij}$ to the reals. $g_{ij}$ is a tensor field defined on $M$. $R$ is the curvature scalar such that $R=R^j_{\;}j$, where $R_{ij}$ is the Ricci tensor. Do the variational calculus and get the Einstein Field Equations.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus why $g_{ij} $ and not $g$ ? I mean
$$ g:\ p\,\longmapsto\, g_p=\sum_{i,j}g_{ij}(p)(dx_i)_p\otimes (dx_j)_p. $$
So is $g_{ij} $ in the formula of E-H action the same as $g_{ij} $ that I have here ?

Comment: Yes, that is the same, the metric tensor field is defined locally at the points $p$ in M. It is basically defined on the tangent space at $p$, $T_p$.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus okay, compare the E-H action to the definition of the variational operator that I stated above, what is the space $H$, the subset $A$ and the subspace $M$ ?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there

Comment: The function $J: A \to \mathbb{R}$ is the action $S_{EH}$, which maps from the space of valid metrics to the reals, so $A$ is the space of symmetric two-tensors on the background smooth manifold.  I'm not entirely sure that this is a Hilbert space, though...  but my impression is that Brézis names all of these subsets just for some more generality and to call attention to the domain and image of the operator $J$.  You could've started out saying that $A$ is the whole Hilbert space and nothing would've changed.

Comment: @RokasVeitas is it true that the variation $\,\displaystyle\frac{\delta S_{EH}}{\delta g_{ij}} $ is given by the Gateaux derivative of $S_{EH}$ in direction $g_{ij} $ ?

Comment: I don't understand when the Gateaux/Fréchet/other functional derivatives exist or the relationship between them, so I can't answer with certainty.  But the way that physicists usually think about these things is that we never expect to have to deal with all that—they are different ways of formalizing the functional derivative, but you don't need to be particularly formal or functional analysis-y in order to do computations with or understand the E-H action as physicists do.

Comment: @RokasVeitas yeah, but the fact is I am writng an analysis thesis in which relevant to this Hilbert action, and since it is analysis, the mathematics is required to be strict, where I have to state what is a variation, what are the concepts that I use to define it, and after all that I am permitted to do the calculating work